# Scroll methods not supported in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I have developed a chat app in Laravel and Vue.js with pusher. It's working properly in all browsers but Internet Explorer is not supporting scroll method. I have installed v-chat-scroll library for scrolling.

Below mentioned errors occurring in console:

> [Vue warn]: Error in directive chat-scroll inserted hook:
>
> "`TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'scroll'`"
>
> Object doesn't support property or method 'scroll'

If anyone has the solution then please enlighten me.

Comment: var scrollToBottom = function scrollToBottom(el, smooth) {
  el.scroll({
    top: el.scrollHeight,
    behavior: smooth ? 'smooth' : 'instant'
  });
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",    "laravel-echo": "^1.4.0",    "pusher-js": "^4.2.2",    "v-toaster": "^1.0.3",    "vue-chat-scroll": "^1.3.3"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

In a practical sense, and if you use compilation for your project, you can try to add at the top of your entry point

```
import 'core-js'
```

At the moment [core-js polyfill library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) is the easiest way to make Cross Browser Support